# Regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r

I am having some troubles with the regular expression in R. I use str_extract from the library stringr and my problem is :

```
library(stringr)
test="word1 something word2 something word3 something word3"
temp = str_extract(test,'word2.+word3')
print(temp)
## [1] "word2 something word3 something word3"
```

The problem is that I want it to stop at the first word3, I don't want the last part of the string.
Any idea please ? thank you very much

and if I have

```
test="word1 something word2 something1 word3 something2 word3 something3 word2 something4 word3"
```

and that I want to keep a 2 size vector like this "word2 something1 word3", "word2 something4 word3"
thanks again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your regex line to:

```
temp = str_extract(test,'word2.+?word3')
                                ^
```

Notice that I added `?` which makes the `.+` non greedy (i.e. it captures as little as possible as opposed to capture everything before the next term in the regex).

To extract all the occurrences, use:

```
temp = str_extract_all(test,'word2.+?word3')
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I have to wait a bit before accepting the answer, I will as soon as I can !

Comment: Do you please know how to do if I want to keep all the sentences that becomes with word2 and ends with word3 and not the only one please ?

Comment: @user1836529 Thanks! I'm not sure I understand your next question though... Could you rephrase it? Maybe an example?

Comment: @user1836529 Can you check my edited line? I'm not familiar with R, but hopefully, this works!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're trying to extract every occurrence between two points in a string.  If I'm wrong my apologies.  This can be accomplished with `qdap's` `genXtract` and setting `with = TRUE`.  Also this is not a `stringr` answer:

```
test="word1 something word2 something1 word3 something2 word3 something3 word2 something4 word3"

library(qdap)
genXtract(test, left = "word2", right = "word3", with=TRUE)

## > genXtract(test, "word2", "word3", with=TRUE)
##         word2  :  word31         word2  :  word32 
## "word2 something1 word3" "word2 something4 word3"
```

Answer (score 0):

using base r: We can capture all the output before word3 by using a backreference

```
 sub("(word3).*","\\1",test)
 [1] "word1 something word2 something word3"
```